# "Meteor create my-app" taking forever installing npm dependencies

Tags: meteor

I am a newbie in web development. I have installed Meteor on ubuntu. When I try to create an app using something like:

Meteor create my-app

It creates the my-app folder but it never returns out of "Installing npm dependencies". I have been waiting for more than half and hour. I was wondering if this is normal? How long more should I wait for it to end?

I'm working behind a company proxy but I have set the proxy using the following lines (and that allowed me to install Meteor in the first place):

export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy:port

export https_proxy=http://username:password@proxy:port

Comment: Looks like npm [has it's own proxy settings](https://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy/) So maybe exit out of the installer, add the config with `meteor npm config` and then run `meteor npm install`?

Comment: Thank you Fred for your comment:

I used the following commands with the right username, password and proxy:

meteor npm config set proxy http://username:password@proxy:port
meteor npm config set https-proxy http://username:password@proxy:port

I tried "meteor npm install" but got the following error

npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '....

Then I tried "Meteor create my-app" and it is again stuck at "installing npm dependencies" for a few minutes now

Comment: Did it ever get unstuck from `Installing npm dependencies...`, @Pezh ?  I'm running into a similar issue.

Answer (score 4):

I was stuck in a similar situation on Windows.

Cancel the job using `ctrl+c`. Since meteor creates the app directory even before the command is complete, you will have the directory intact, go into the directory and run

```
meteor npm install
```

It will install all the dependencies (took 7s for me),
then run `meteor` to start the server.